# Desktop back in the task switcher (Alt + Tab)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

With ubuntu unity I had the possibility to have "Desktop" as task in the task switcher (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). In Ubuntu 18.04 this possibility is gone.

Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: You could install this Gnome extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/ or this software: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/26/enable-coverflow-alt-tab-task-switcher-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/ It might be not exactly the same, but maybe close enough?

Comment: Coverflow-Alt-Tab could also be istalled as [Gnome extension] https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/ but there is no option to show desktop afaik

Comment: show desktop button extension does not show desktop in the task switcher but halps as workaround